# Hide the alert of the Knockout JS when the page gets rendered

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm using knockout validation in my asp.net MVC code. the knockout validation messages in the div control also gets flashed while the page gets loaded..

```
<div class="alert alert-danger  alert-dismissable" data-bind="visible:shouldShowalert">
    Please enter or select value of any of the fields..<a class="alert-link" href="#"></a>.
</div>
<div class="alert alert-info  alert-dismissable" data-bind="visible:shouldShowrecordalert">
    No records found..<a class="alert-link" href="#"></a>.
</div>
```

both these div gets displayed while page load..!

How to avoid this situation? can any one help me get rid of this situation!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Probably the simplest is to just put `display: none` in their `style` attribute:

```
<div style="display: none" class="alert alert-danger  alert-dismissable" data-bind="visible:shouldShowalert">
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's the style value that KO uses with `visible`, so `visible` will take over when the page is rendered and KO applied. Until then, the divs won't be visible.